# JavaScript, MegaPixImage - upload file to server after "fix"

Tags: javascript

So I'm aware that the new resize image on browser has a bug in IOS 6.xxx and after much reading I now there we can fix it using some javascript tools.

I'm now trying this [MegaPixImage](https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel/blob/master/test/megapix-image.test.html) wich seems to do the trick.
The problem is I can't find a way of after fix upload the image to my webserver.

My question is, Did someone find a way of upload after fix? How?

Thanks,

Pluda

Comment: From a quick glance, I'd assume that one would use the toDataURL function of the target canvas, followed by your preferred method of upload - perhaps a hidden input element or simply with ajax.

Comment: yes, inside the function renderImageToCanvas, at the end, we need to add the upload command like upload(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", options.quality || 1); This will do the trick. Thanks!